# python- combining list and making them a dictionary

Tags: python

I have two list

```
one=[1,3]
elements=["a","b","c","d"]
```

So, I want to create a dictionary- where `one` is treated as key and `elements` treated as values and output should be like this

```
{'1': ['a'], '3': [["b"],["c"],["d"]] }
```

Comment: There are more values than keys.  How should they be divided?  You haven't told us.

Comment: okay! So `one` and `elements` are not fixed. they are arbitrary.But its always `len(elements)>'len(one)`. If suppose `len(one) is 3 `[2,1,5]`  then `key 2` will have `element[0] and element[1]` as values . `key1` will have `element[2]` as values and `key5` will have `element[3] element[4] element[5] element[6] element[7]` as value

Comment: So basically the keys are defining the number of values linked

Comment: Your example has integer values in `one`, but string values as keys in the dict.  Is this intentional?

Comment: yes.. My elements are mix of integers and strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that should work for an arbitrary length of `one`:

```
d = {}

# Create a 1-to-1 mapping for the first n-1 items in `one`
for i in one[:-1]:
    d[i] = [elements.pop(0)]

# Append the remainder of `elements`
d[one[-1]] = [elements]
```

Or with a dict-comp:

```
d = {i:[elements.pop(0)] for i in one[:-1]}.
d[one[-1]] = [elements]
```

Or in one nice easy-to-read line:

```
d = {i:[elements.pop(0)] for i in one[:-1]}.update({one[-1]:[elements]})
```

Comment: @zondo Why? I'm iterating over `one[:-1]`, not the whole list

Comment: To the casual observer (I include myself) it would appear that `d[one[-1]] = elements` is overwriting `d[one[-1]]`, but since `one[:-1]` is being used instead of `one`, `d[one[-1]]` has not yet been defined.  I mention this so that nobody makes the mistake that I almost did of down-voting the answer for its incorrectness.

Comment: `extend` won't work though; isn't `d[one[-1]]` going to be equal to a character? It's not a list yet

Comment: Yes.  You are right, but it *should* be a list.  You *should* use `i: [elements.pop(0)]`.  The OP wants a list regardless of how many elements it has.

Comment: @zondo Well spotted! I'll fix it

Comment: your output is `{1: 'a', 3: ['b', 'c', 'd']}` but it should be `{1: 'a', 3: [['b'],[ c'], ['d']]}`

Comment: @user5661083 It should be fixed now. You've specified the output as `{1: ['a'], 3: [['b'],[ c'], ['d']]}` in the OP, which contradicts that comment; you can fix it either way you want though

Comment: @user5661083 I'm flattered you accepted this answer but I think Aswin Murugesh's is what you actually need rather than this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the length of elements is always >= length of one, and assuming you try to map one on one between one and elements:

```
d= {}
for item in one:
    d[str(item)] = element[:item]
    del element[:item]
```

So this will create a list as per your example

Comment: @zondo Used this so that OP might understand better. But pop seems fine..  Will use it

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that the items in `item` specify how many `elements` to key to! This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try splicing the list in each iteration for your key value, this should also also take care of elements not being available based on `len(key)`

```
outDict = {}
start = 0
for key in keys:
    outDict[str(key)] = elements[start:start+key]
    start+=key

print(outDict)
```

Running it for something like this

```
keys=[1,2,3]
elements=["a","b","c"]
```

> > {'1': ['a'], '2': ['b', 'c'], '3': []}